# Proof that if $a$ is coprime to $n$ in $R = \mathbb{Z}/(n)$, then $a$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Proof that if $a$ is coprime to $n$ in $R = \mathbb{Z}/(n)$, then $a$ is  a unit

Let $a \in R$ be coprime to $n$.

Then $gcd(a, n) = 1$

$\implies a\nmid n$

Let $b \in R$.

Now as $a \nmid n$ we have that $ba \neq 0$

I.e. $ba \in \{1,...,n-1\}$

I.e. ba will eventually 'hit' all numbers in $\{1, 2, ...n-1\}$, and in particular for some value of $b$ we will get that $ba = 1$.

Comment: Actually, unless you specify $b\not\equiv 0\pmod n$, you get hits on all the numbers $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.  You have proven that $a$ is invertible, does this automatically imply that $a$ is a unit?

Comment: Try looking at [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: @abiessu Yes if it is invertible it is a unit as we have that there exists an $a^{-1}$ and $a \cdot a^{-1}$ = 1.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is wrong.

- You deduce everything from the statement $a \not\mid n$. This is intuitively wrong: for example $4 \not\mid 6$, but 4 is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$.
- Even though $a \not\mid n$, it is possible that there is a $b$ such that $ba = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$. For example, $3 \cdot 4 = 12 \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$.
- How do you prove that $ba$ will eventually hit all the numbers in $\{1,...,n-1\}$?

The best way to prove this fact is Bezout's theorem.

Comment: Well using Bezout's theorem we have that as $gcd(a, n) = 1$ then there exists $x,y$ such that $1 = ax + ny$. Modding both sides by $n$ we have that $1 = \overline{a}\overline{x}$. So hence $a$ is a unit?

Comment: @sonicboom: Yes exactly.

Comment: And as $\overline{a}\overline{x} = 1$ we have that we can hit all numbers in $S = \{1,..., n-1\}$ by considering $(\overline{a} \cdot \overline{x}) \cdot S_i$, where $S_i \in S$. And equivalently $\overline{a} \cdot (\overline{x} \cdot S_i)$ will hit all the numbers in $S$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach doesn't quite work. Take $n=12$ and $a=9$. $9\nmid 12$ but $9\cdot 4\equiv 0$.

If $\gcd(a,n)=1$, you find $x$ and $y$ so that $ax+ny=1$ (why?).

Now reduce the equation modulo $n$. You see that $\bar a\bar x+\bar 0=1$. So $\bar x$ is an inverse for $\bar a$ in $\mathbb Z/(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Not to answer a question with another question, but:

What about the old saw that $\gcd(a, n) = 1$ implies there exist $c, d \in \Bbb Z$ with $ac + dn =1$ whence, reducing $\mod n$, we have $ac = 1$ in $R$, so $a$ is a unit in $R$?

Hmmm . . . I guess that's the Bezout's identity approach . . . just checked out robjohn's comment.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @ sonicboom and One and All:  I parsed this question as, "if $a$ and $n$ are coprime in $\Bbb Z$, then $a$ is a unit in $R = \Bbb Z/(n)$", since saying $a$ is coprime to $n$ in $R$ is tantamount to assuming $a$ is coprime to $0$ in $R$.  Judging by the other comments answers, it seems I am in accord with generally accepted usage, no?